# isc-dhcp-server Computers not receiving IP addresses

Tags: networking, server, dhcp

I originally ran `isc-dhcp-server` on a Raspberry Pi [until I deleted /lib by accident](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/44424/i-deleted-lib-how-can-i-get-it-back). I managed to get `/etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf`. I installed `isc-dhcp-server` with `sudo apt-get install isc-dhcp-server`. Now, if I look at `syslog`, I see `DHCPOFFER` and `DHCPDISCOVER` in the log but the computer never gets an IP.

For instance, I see about a dozen different variations of this:

```
Mar 23 19:47:00 server dhcpd: No hostname for 192.168.0.118
Mar 23 19:47:00 server dhcpd: DHCPDISCOVER from 00:00:00:00:00:00 (client) via p1p1
Mar 23 19:47:00 server dhcpd: DHCPOFFER on 192.168.0.118 to 00:00:00:00:00:00 (box) via p1p1
```

And occasionally I see this:

```
DHCPACK on 192.168.0.144 to 00:00:00:00:00:00 via p1p1
```

00:00:00:00:00:00 isn't the actual MAC address.

`/etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf` is:

```
authoritative;
ddns-update-style none;
option local-proxy-config code 252 = text;
option domain-name "net.MYCOOLNETWORK";
option server.ddns-domainname = config-option domain-name;

subnet 192.168.0.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
authoritative;
option routers 192.168.0.1;
option broadcast-address 192.168.0.255;
option subnet-mask 255.255.255.0;
option domain-name-servers 192.168.0.4;
option local-proxy-config "http://192.168.0.4:80/wpad.dat";
option domain-name "net.strodl";
option server.ddns-domainname = config-option domain-name;
#   option ddns-domain-name "net.strodl";
option domain-search "net.strodl";
range dynamic-bootp 192.168.0.3 192.168.0.254;
default-lease-time 21600;
max-lease-time 43200;
get-lease-hostnames true;
use-host-decl-names on;

filename "pxelinux.0";

allow booting;
#   allow bootp;

host wpad {
    hardware ethernet D0:50:99:51:3D:2C;
    fixed-address 192.168.0.4;
#       host-name wpad;
}

host hpmain {
    hardware ethernet 00:11:2F:14:65:E9;
    fixed-address 192.168.0.99;
}

host routere900 {
    hardware ethernet 20:AA:4B:D4:91:91;
    fixed-address 192.168.0.7;
}

host mainlinksys {
    hardware ethernet 00:18:F8:17:C3:AB;
    fixed-address 192.168.0.128;
}

host dellmain {
    hardware ethernet 6C:33:A9:8F:4D:3E;
    fixed-address 192.168.0.118;
}

host imac1 {
    option host-name "imac1";
    # change your hardware address here
    hardware ethernet 00:0a:27:b3:57:08;
    # change your address here if needed
    fixed-address 192.168.0.70;
}

host canonmx430 {
    hardware ethernet 2C:9E:FC:C0:F7:45;
    fixed-address 192.168.0.246;
}

host magicjack {
    hardware ethernet 6c:33:a9:8f:4d:3e;
    fixed-address 192.168.0.87;
}

host wrt54g {
    hardware ethernet 00:90:4C:91:00:02;
    fixed-address 192.168.0.90;
}

host piplexconnect {
    hardware ethernet 00:21:2f:39:61:50;
    fixed-address 192.168.0.16;
}

group {
    next-server 192.168.0.2;
    host tftpclient {
        filename "pxelinux.0";
    }
}

}

   host piplexconnect {
        hardware ethernet 00:21:2f:39:61:50;
        fixed-address 192.168.0.16;
   }

    group {
        next-server 192.168.0.2;
        host tftpclient {
            filename "pxelinux.0";
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Hmm. Not enough rep to comment so... Any reason you have authoritative twice; once globally and once for you subnet? Also, shouldn't your range NOT include 192.168.0.4 which is a static IP, so you should start from 192.168.0.5 and also NOT include 192.168.0.99 which is also statically assigned? Not sure how correct that is as I've read conflicting reports during my own research.